# Cant understand the reason of error Illegal use of pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <conio>
    #include <math>

    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {
        double b[1000], mxrs[1000],mnrs[1000], ls[1000]; int t, i;
        clrscr();
        cin>>t;
        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        cin>>b[i]>>ls[i];
        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            mxrs[i]=sqrt(ls*ls+b*b);
            mnrs[i]=sqrt(ls*ls-b*b); cout<<mnrs[i]<<' '<<mxrs[i]<<'\n';
        }
        getch();
    }
```

I get 4 errors in this code...

> main.cpp|16|Error E2087 : Illegal use of pointer in function main()|
>   main.cpp|16|Error E2087 : Illegal use of pointer in function main()|
>   main.cpp|17|Error E2087 : Illegal use of pointer in function main()|
>   main.cpp|17|Error E2087 : Illegal use of pointer in function main()|
>   ||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Please help me in correcting the errors, it would be helpful even if you told me only reason of errors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `b*b` supposed to do? `b` is an array.

Comment: Um, you're referencing `ls` and `b` as if they were numbers; you need to add an index to each reference.

Comment: Already your return type of main is wrong

Comment: What is '#include <math>'? You probably want to use 'cmath'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `double b[1000]`, you can access the array elements either by writing `b[n]` or `*(b + n)`, taking care to keep `n` within the *bounds* of the array.

So `*b` and `b[0]` are equivalent. In other words, `b` is a *pointer* to the zeroth element of the array. Writing `b * b` is an attempt to multiply two pointers and that makes no sense. This is what the compiler is telling you.

To multiply elements of the array, use `b[n] * b[m]` or `*(b + n) * *(b + m)`.

(And fix the return type of `main`: it should be `int`.)

Comment: I was a noob back then, didn't see that this was such an idiotic question. Looking back at this now, I'm ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

`ls,bs` refers to the base address of the array. so they are addresses not values. I think this is what you intend to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
#include <math>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double b[1000], mxrs[1000],mnrs[1000], ls[1000]; int t, i;
    clrscr();
    cin>>t;
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    cin>>b[i]>>ls[i];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        mxrs[i]=sqrt(ls[i]*ls[i]+b[i]*b[i]);
        mnrs[i]=sqrt(ls[i]*ls[i]-b[i]*b[i]); cout<<mnrs[i]<<' '<<mxrs[i]<<'\n';
    }
    getch();
}
```

let's take an simple example to understand the concept:

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
cout<<*a; //prints the value at base address which is 1 as a refers to a[0]
cout<<a[0]; //prints 1 
cout<<*(a+1); //prints 2 ... as a+1 refers to the address next to its base which is a[1] and which is 2   
cout<<a[1];//prints 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You put `#include <math>`, it should have been `#include <math.h>`. Same thing for `<iostream>` and `<conio>`. You forgot `.h` on all of them.

Comment: Please read question tags. This is a `C++` question and omitting the `.h` part when including a header is allowed.